# Paste[] to same cell or CurrentClipboardContents[]?

Tags: front-end, clipboard

I tried using Mathematica for watching my clipboard contents.

`Paste[]` creates a new cell each time it is evaluated though.

- Is there a way to make `Paste[]` not create a new cell?
- Is there some other function that is more like `CurrentClipboardContents[]`!?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have found a function in the Function Repository.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClipboardContent/

Answer (score 0):

Using `` JLink` ``

```
PasteContents[writer_:Identity] := (
Needs["JLink`"];
JavaBlock[
    InstallJava[];

    LoadJavaClass /@ {
        "java.awt.Toolkit",
        "java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard",
        "java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor",
        "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream",
        "javax.imageio.ImageIO"
    };

    Block[{clip},
        clip = Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]
                         @getSystemClipboard[]         
                         @getContents[Null];
        Which[
            clip@isDataFlavorSupported[DataFlavor`stringFlavor],
                writer@clip@getTransferData[DataFlavor`stringFlavor],
            clip@isDataFlavorSupported[DataFlavor`imageFlavor], 
                writer@Block[{bytesOs},
                    bytesOs = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
                    ImageIO`write[clip@getTransferData[DataFlavor`imageFlavor], "gif", bytesOs];
                    ImportByteArray@ByteArray[
                        Mod[bytesOs @ toByteArray[], 256]]
                ],
            clip@isDataFlavorSupported[DataFlavor`javaFileListFlavor],
                writer@Block[{files},
                    files = Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]
                                         @getSystemClipboard[]        
                                         @getContents[Null]           
                                         @getTransferData[DataFlavor`javaFileListFlavor]
                                         @toArray[];
                     File[(# @ getPath[])]& /@ files
                ],
            True, Failure["Unsupported", 
                <|
                    "MessageTemplate"->"Type of contents in clipboard(possible types: `Types`) is unsupported.",
                    "MessageParameters"-><|
                        "Types" -> (
                            #@getHumanPresentableName[]& /@ clip@getTransferDataFlavors[]
                        )
                    |>
                |>]
]]]);
```

When `writer` is:

- `Identity`, resulting to raw object, such as `String`, `Image` etc.;
- `ToExpression`, trying to convert string into wolfram language expression;
- `NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], BoxData[If[StringQ@#, #, ToBoxes@#]]]&`, just like `Paste`.